# Transparent texture becomes black when exported to FBX

Tags: texturing, transparency, .fbx

I created a plane and added an PNG that included some transparent part as texture to the plane.
Then added some shader node to make the transparent part transparent following this tutorial:
[Add a transparent image on top of a material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material)
Blend Mode is set to Alpha Clip.
However, after the object being exported to FBX, the transparent part become black.
Is there any step I missed?

[image: Added a plane and added partly transparent PNG as texture]

[image: Blend Mode set to Alpha Clip]

[image: Alpha connected to Alpha]

[image: Export Setting]

[image: Becomes Black in FBX]

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of the exporter and/or the FBX format. Most formats Blender can export to do not do things the same way Blender does, so Blender must translate or reduce, and it usually has reduced. Shader node materials in particular usually have gotten reduced to the active image textures alone.